# I'm want to drop text of canvas.. help me

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

To respected developer.

before write this question, I'm weak english.

I'm studying javascript.

but one problem is work..

I'm want to drop text of canvas.. but.. I'm don't know how drop this text..

how modify this code..?   please help me..

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">


 var Text_array = new Array("exam1", "exam2", "exam3");
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = "30px Arial";
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(Text_array[i], 100 * i + 10, 50);
 }

function removeText()
{
 var removeText = document.getElementById("txtWord").value;
 var position = Text_array.indexOf(removeText);
 if( position  > -1)
 {
  Text_array.splice(position,1);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  for (i = 0; i < Text_array.length; i++) {
          ctx.fillText(Text_array[i], 100 * i + 10, 50);
   }  
 }
}
 </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">

    .box {
            position: relative;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
     }
         .box canvas {
                border: 1px solid red;
         }
         .box .control {
                position: relative;
                bottom: 30px;
                z-index: 999;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                display: inline-block;
         }
            .box .control input {
                    float: left;
                    width: 45%;
             }
             .box .control button {
                    float: right;
                    width: 45%;
                    color: #000;
                   margin-right: 15px;
             }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="box">
     
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
         Your browser does not support the canvas element.
     </canvas>
     <div class="control">
         <input id="txtWord" type="text" name="word" value=""> 
         <button type="button" class="btn" title="" onclick="javascript:removeText();" >Btn</button>
     </div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You're using removeText for both function name and variable btw.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with this code, just I removed `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` form code, Its working...

```js
 var Text_array = new Array("exam1", "exam2", "exam3");
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = "30px Arial";
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(Text_array[i], 100 * i + 10, 50);
 }

function removeText()
{
 var removeText = document.getElementById("txtWord").value;
 var position = Text_array.indexOf(removeText);
 if( position  > -1)
 {
  Text_array.splice(position,1);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  for (i = 0; i < Text_array.length; i++) {
          ctx.fillText(Text_array[i], 100 * i + 10, 50);
   }  
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">

    .box {
            position: relative;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
     }
         .box canvas {
                border: 1px solid red;
         }
         .box .control {
                position: relative;
                bottom: 30px;
                z-index: 999;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                display: inline-block;
         }
            .box .control input {
                    float: left;
                    width: 45%;
             }
             .box .control button {
                    float: right;
                    width: 45%;
                    color: #000;
                   margin-right: 15px;
             }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="box">
     
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
         Your browser does not support the canvas element.
     </canvas>
     <div class="control">
         <input id="txtWord" type="text" name="word" value=""> 
         <button type="button" class="btn" title="" onclick="javascript:removeText();" >Btn</button>
     </div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: fillText() does not operate on a path so there is no need for fill() (you can see this by commenting it out in your jsbin)